# output format in string builder, jaxb sax

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jaxb, sax

I am writing a sample servlet class which invokes service method. Service method need to validate the user name and password.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new UserServiceImpl().login(name, password));
    }
    public String login(String username, String password) {
        StringBuilder validUser = new StringBuilder();
        if(username == null || password == null){           
            return invalidUser();
        }
        if((validUsers.contains(name) && validPassword.contains(password))){    
            validUser.append("<user>");
            validUser.append("<username>");
            validUser.append(username);
            validUser.append("</username>");
            validUser.append("<firstname>");
            validUser.append("Mr M");
            validUser.append("</firstname>");
            validUser.append("<lastname>");
            validUser.append("Tom");
            validUser.append("</lastname>");
            validUser.append("</user>");
            return validUser.toString();
        }
        else{
            return invalidUser();
        }
    }
    private String invalidUser() {
         StringBuilder invalidUser = new StringBuilder();
         invalidUser.append("<status>");
         invalidUser.append("<code>");
         invalidUser.append("401");
         invalidUser.append("</code>");
         invalidUser.append("<message>");
         invalidUser.append("Invalid Credentials");
         invalidUser.append("</message>");
         invalidUser.append("</status>");        
         return invalidUser.toString();
    }
```

A form submit should trigger the LoginServlet, from which the username and password are passed to UserService.login. If the username and password are validated (if statement is fine) an user xml string should be returned:

```
<user><username></username><firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname></user>
```

Otherwise, a status xml string should be returned:

```
<status><code>401</code><message>Invalid Credentials</message></status>
```

In this case I am trying to use StringBuilder to make above format. Is there any different approach I can try? like JaxB or Sax or Dom, which one is better to make above format? String builder is the best to fit in this case?

In my servlet class I need to return to view page i.e welcome page if valid user, otherwise an error message page with error details.

Comment: The context of this question is unclear to me. Is this your Servlet class (and, are you really validating user and password "combinations" like this)?

Comment: @ drvdijk, updated question, changes are after main java code.

Answer (score 0):

SAX is one way parser - you can only read XML with it. JAXB is a too much unless you want to extensively work with XML. DOM is a good alternative, but only an alternative -  StringBuilder for simple XML is simpler and as long as produce the correct XML it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As According To me Jaxb Is the  best method where we have to generate a xml file. It is the best and easiest way. Here is an example of jaxb.

### JaxbGetterSetter.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Data")

public class JaxbGetterSetter {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    @XmlElement
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

### JaxbMarshaller.java

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JaxbMarshaller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      JaxbGetterSetter jaxbGetterSetter = new JaxbGetterSetter();
      jaxbGetterSetter.setId(100);
      jaxbGetterSetter.setName("Pritpal Singh");
      jaxbGetterSetter.setAge(24);

      try {

        File file = new File("/root/Desktop/jaxbExample.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbGetterSetter.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbGetterSetter, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbGetterSetter, System.out);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
}
```